# How do I disable the "theme loaded" message in zsh

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm, zsh

Im using zsh as my default shell and loving it. I have random themes enabled, and whenever I load a theme it displays a message on my terminal. How do I disable this message?

Im talking about
`[oh-my-zsh] Random theme '/Users/r3dsm0k3/.oh-my-zsh/themes/ys.zsh-theme' loaded...`

How to disable it from showing in the terminal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comment out:

- line 77 of `~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh` (beginning with `echo`)
- line 9 of `~/.oh-my-zsh/plugins/themes/themes.plugin.zsh` (beginning with `echo`)

Comment: Thank you very much, I feel stupid for not grepping in the first place. :)